# Find all provided jars in Websphere

Tags: java, maven, websphere, websphere-8

I'm using the Websphere Application Server 8.5.5.6 and 8.5.5.8 and from time to time run into problems when some jar or the other in my application conflicts with one that is already present on the WAS. It's easy to fix of course, simply mark the dependency as "provided" in maven and there you go, but since IBM seemingly choose to write the AS with the most obscure error messages possible it takes ages to find something like that out.

My question which google hasn't been able to answer so far:

> Is there a complete list somewhere which libraries in which versions are provided with Websphere?

Comment: For clarity, can you provide a couple of example for these conflicting JAR files?

Comment: Openwebbeans is always a candidate for problems. Took us ages the first time to find that one out.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're referring primarily to Open Source packages, the official list is here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/opensourcesoftwareapis.html

Beyond that, most of the stuff visible to apps should be Java EE/SE APIs, which I assume you were already expecting, and IBM-specific implementations (things in com.ibm.* packages), which are hopefully at low risk of collision.

Answer (score 1):

At least if you are on Windows: take Process Monitor (not Process Explorer), and fire it up filtering on Path contains .jar. Then start WebSphere. At some point it will starting loading jars from various directories. Process Monitor will show you which are those jars, and where they are being loaded from.

This should provide you with first hand information without reading IBM documents.

Besides, probably you are aware of that, but in any case: you should be careful with marking a dependency as "provided", since the version of the library used by your application might differ from the version used by WebSphere.